# ReSharper error at valid css-property

Tags: html, css, resharper

I have a css-file which was not written by myself. `ReSharper` is throwing an error at

```
text-overflow: initial;
```

stating, `Expected one of: clip, ellipsis, ellipsis-word, <string>.`.

Reading [@w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp), `initial` is a valid value.

My question is: Can I disable this error without having to fear any invalid css or should it be changed to `clip` as this seems to be the default value?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a ReSharper bug. `initial` is completely valid on the `text-overflow`. However as you say it does default to `clip`, so if you want to avoid the error then setting it directly to `clip` should serve the same purpose.

If you don't want that approach, I believe ReSharper allows you to ignore certain errors. It's been a long time since I've used it though so I'm not 100% sure. This may be relevant: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/10.0/Code_Analysis__Solution-Wide_Analysis__Configuring_Solution-Wide_Analysis.html

Comment: There is an option to ignore it once by comment, which will add `/* ReSharper disable once InvalidValue */`. But, if setting it to `clip` has the same effect, I will go this way as this seems more obvious as `initial` is not directly clear.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like ReSharper doesn't support the `unset`, `initial` and `inherit` CSS3 keywords. I've raised an issue you can track, comment and vote on: [RSRP-458038](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-458038).